# Customize the last three rows of a Tablix in SSRS

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table which is getting data from a query. Because I am not doing any calculation in SSRS, but instead in SQL and only pulling the data, I am having hard time figuring out how to customize the style for the last three rows.

Here is the design view:

[image]

Here is the preview:

[image]

Now as you can see the last three rows are either SUM or AVG of the above numbers. How can I make it so that the table displays a different background color for the bottom three rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add an expression for the text box format for the three rows that says something like:

```
 =IIF(Fields![ARRIVED_DATE].Value="WEEKLY TOTAL","Grey",IIF(Fields![ARRIVED_DATE].Value="Prior Week","Red",IIF(Fields![ARRIVED_DATE].Value="12 WEEK AVERAGE","Green","Transparent")))
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like the entire row to change color. Is that possible or just have to do each textbox individually?

Comment: Actually I wanted the background color of the row to change. With the above code the "WEEKLY TOTAL" is changing from Grey to Silver which is not what I am looking to do.

Comment: You just have to select all the textboxes for that row that you want to change color.  The first condition would say it was Grey if it was Weekly Total or everything else Silver.

Comment: I edited the answer so you can see that you will have to have nested IIFs so it will handle all three ARRIVED_DATE values.

Comment: Thank you. Where should I put that expression, if you don't mind me asking? Should I select TABLE properties? or ROW GROUP properties?

Comment: This will be part of the text box properties.  So you will choose the three text boxes: Theal1, ThealUC, ID171 and choose Text Box Properties and under Fill you can put that Expression.

Comment: So I have to choose individually... I tried hitting CTRL and selecting all three but the Textbox Properties is disabled.

Comment: Yeah if you do all three textboxes the same it should work fine.

Comment: I got an error, `The BackgroundColor expression for the text box 'theall' contains an error: [BC30311] Value of type 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Field; cannot be converted to 'String'`

Comment: Try without the "" around the colors.

Comment: Use single quote instead? If i remove the quotes around the color, there is a red squiggly line under it.

Comment: When I looked it should be the double quotes as I thought.  Can you paste the expression you are using [link](http://sqlserverreportingservices.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/conditional-formatting-in-ssrs/)

Comment: =IIF(Fields!ARRIVED_DATE="WEEKLY TOTAL","Grey",IIF(Fields!ARRIVED_DATE="Prior Week","Red",IIF(Fields!ARRIVED_DATE="12 WEEK AVERAGE","Green","Transparent")))

Comment: You have to change it to:
=IIF(Fields!ARRIVED_DATE.Value="WEEKLY TOTAL","Grey",IIF(Fields!ARRIVED_DATE.Value="Prior Week","Red",IIF(Fields!ARRIVED_DATE.Value="12 WEEK AVERAGE","Green","Transparent")))

Comment: When I select multiple textboxes the "textbox properties" option from the menu is disabled. I am guessing I have to do it individually one box at a time :/

Comment: Only the `12 weeks average` is GREEN but the rest of the textboxes are still default transparent.

Comment: I ended up using a SWITCH statement which was much easier to troubleshoot and manage. Thank you :) You gave me the lead...

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your point correctly this would be the solution 
 =iif(total number of records(int)=rownumber(nothing), "Color1",iif(total number of records(int)-1=rownumber(nothing),"Color2",iif(total number of records(int)-2=rownumber(nothing),"Color3",""))) 
 use this expression in Background color of row properties.

Comment: Thanks. How do I get to the row properties? I have `Tablix properties` and `Row Group > Group Properties`. `total number of records` is derived how?